# cannot switch on the microsoft update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates

I haven't turned on the windows 7 box for about 9 months. When I try to check the updates, it is supper slow. So I turned of the update other Microsoft product option in `windows update -> Change settings`. After about 40hours calculation the windows update finally figured out all updates it required. After installed all updates, I reboot the computer.

Everything seems fine. However, when I click the `find out more` in `Windows update -> get updates for other microsoft products`. It directed me to this url:
http://www.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/thanks.aspx?ln=en&&thankspage=5

instead of:

[image]

So I cannot switch on `Microsoft update` any more. When I try to directly update the Office/VS in `File->help->check for updates'. It brought me to the same URL.

Since I've already turned off the `microsoft update`, the checkbox in `change setting` for it has gone.

How can I re-enable the `Microsoft update` right now?

Comment: You clicked "Find out more" which is to take you to help, to explain more about the option, which is what you say it's doing, so I'm confused as to why you think you can't continue to use Windows Update.. Please edit your question to add more information (preferably with screenshots) that explains exactly how you're trying to turn WU back on, as-is it's unclear.

Comment: @Techie007 please see the update. It does not show me the correct interface as the figure I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/153b7ba7-e5b5-4c3a-af07-23c7980f79ea/cant-get-windows-update-to-download-updates-for-other-ms-products?forum=w7itproinstall).

```
- add *.microsoft.com in Internet Explorer 11 to trusted sites

- add microsoft.com in IE to compatibility view

Apply, close IE then press once again Find out more.
```